# Strange things when converting an export script from 2.43 to 2.62+

Tags: scripting

I am currently converting an export script that was written for blender 2.43 to blender 2.6+. All in all it goes pretty well, but I do have 2 slight problems. Number one is, vertex normals are sometimes different. Mostly they are off by very little, like where blender 2.43 returned something like

```
x=1.000000 y=0.000000 z=0.000000
```

with blender 2.62 I see

```
x=0.999969 y=0.000000 z=0.000000
```

which looks like a rounding problem. However, sometimes (quite rare) they are really off, like 2.43 returned

```
x=0.000000 y=1.000000 z=0.000000
```

and with 2.62 I get

```
x=-0.057955 y=0.998169 z=0.015503
```

Any idea what is going on here?

The other thing I see is this: in the old script, PoseBone matrices were exported by using the PoseBone's localMatrix property. For 2.62 and later, the PoseBone.matrix_basis seems to be the same, except for 2 things. One is, I have to transpose matrix_basis to have the values in the same places as for localMatrix. The other thing here is that matrix_basis seems to be missing the position component.

Again, any idea what I am doing wrong?